# circular buffer "requestBufferSize: of couchbase

Tags: couchbase

What is requestBufferSize of couchbase 2.0 ? Doc says its circular buffer for I/O but is it number of key-calue pair of size of key-value pair ? if it is size then is it KB or MB ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the size in bytes. On several discussions/bug reports I've seen terminology used as "default 16K buffer".

Now looking at the description:

> Default: **16384**. The size of the request ring buffer where all request initially are
>   stored and then picked up to be pushed onto the I/O threads. Tuning
>   this to a lower value will more quickly lead to BackpressureExceptions
>   during overload or failure scenarios. Setting it to a higher value
>   means backpressure will take longer to occur, but more requests will
>   potentially be queued up and more heap space is used.

You can see that its referred as "default 16K buffer".